# how can I force android app to wait when anr shown?

Tags: java, android

I only need to make my android application responsive even if there are long time operations on UI Thread.
i tried this piece of code on onCrearte:

```
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog()
                .penaltyDeath()
                .build());
```

but there is nothing happened and i still get **ANR** dialog message.
**Any help?**

Comment: Move the "long time operations" off the main application thread. This is not something that is controlled via `StrictMode`.

Comment: Always do long operations on background threads. [Coroutines](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-on-android-part-i-getting-the-background-3e0e54d20bb/) is one of the simplest way to do it. If you want to have more control over things, use [work manager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/).

Comment: @CommonsWare I discovered that the error comes from backButton pressing while the UI thread printing(POSPrinter Machine).